# Como mandar una variable por referencia con python

Tags: python

Necesito que una variable mandarla por referencia, luego sumarle una constante y que la variable se actualize con dicho valor

```
interfaceLectorNotas.geometry("800x600")
lienzo = Canvas(interfaceLectorNotas, width=800, height=600)
lienzo.place(x=0, y=0)

    # Se crean unas entradas por defecto
    informacion = {"a.txt":"aaaa", "b.txt":"bbbb", "c.txt":"cccc", "d.txt":"dddd", "e.txt":"eeee", "f.txt":"ffff", "h.txt":"hhhh"}
    contadorInformacion = 0
    
    
    
    btnNextInformacion = Button(lienzo, text=">>", command= lambda cont=contadorInformacion : _subInterfaceNotasRefrescarInformacionSiguiente(informacion, cont))
    btnNextInformacion.place(x=760, y=300)
    btnPrevInformacion = Button(lienzo, text="<<", command= lambda cont=contadorInformacion : _subInterfaceNotasRefrescarInformacionAnterior(informacion, cont))
    btnPrevInformacion.place(x=10, y=300)

    #Al hacer esto:
    #_subInterfaceNotasRefrescarInformacionSiguiente(informacion, cont):
    #cont = contador + 1
    
    #_subInterfaceNotasRefrescarInformacionAnterior(informacion, cont):
    #cont = cont - 1
```

Contador no guarda el incremento o decremento

La cosa es que necesito que contadorInformacion se le sume 1????

como hago para que el contador guarde la nueva información????

Comment: ¿Cual sería tu código completo? ¿Te tira algún error? ¿Si es así, cual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En algunos lenguajes, es posible modificar el valor de una variable externa a una función trabajando sobre la referencia de la misma en vez del valor. Por eso se habla muchas veces de "call by reference" a una forma en la que se habilita en las funciones, este comportamiento.

En Python, juega el concepto de objetos "mutables" y "no mutables" y los tipos numéricos o cadenas, como es la variable de tu pregunta, ciertamente son "inmutables" por lo que aún pasando una referencia (que de hecho es lo que se pasa en una función) sería imposible usarla para modificar el valor.

Lo que buscas, entiendo, puede resolverse de varias maneras, que en [¿Cómo puedo escribir una función sin parámetros (invocación mediante referencia)?](https://docs.python.org/es/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) están bien documentadas:

#### La más habitual: retornar y asignar el nuevo valor:

```
def suma_uno(variable):
  return variable + 1

cont = 1
cont = suma_uno(cont)
print(cont)
2
```

---

#### La menos recomendada: usar variables globales

```
def suma_uno():
  global cont
  cont = cont + 1

cont = 1
suma_uno()
print(cont)
2
```

---

#### Usar variables mutables: por ejemplo una lista

```
cont = [1]
def suma_uno(variable):
  variable[0] = variable[0] + 1

suma_uno(cont)
print(cont[0])
2
```

---

#### Usar un diccionario

En definitiva también un objeto mutable

```
def suma_uno(args):
  args["cont"] = args["cont"] + 1

args = {"cont" : 1}
suma_uno(args)
print(args["cont"])
```

---

#### Usar un atributo de una instancia de clase:

```
class UnNumero:

  def __init__(self, **args):
    for key, value in args.items():
      setattr(self, key, value)
  
cont = UnNumero(valor=1)

def suma_uno(args):
  args.valor = args.valor + 1
  
suma_uno(cont)
print(cont.valor)
2
```

Comment: Quedaría la instancia que incluye el método para modificar su atributo, método que se pasaría como comando al botón.